# RPG influenced names in Linux/Unix?

Tags: linux, history

I have been reading about Linux and its resources recently and I have been seeing a RPG motif on a number of Linux utilities, for example Linux executables are called ELF files, the Linux manual is abbreviated to `man`, the debugging data format for ELF files is called DWARF and I believe I have seen orc as a name to some other thing in a rapid glance in a text I was reading.

Are there other examples? Is this some type of in-joke? Does it date back to Unix?
Or am I only imagining things?

I am asking this because although it seems to be the case, I have not found any reference to this being pointed out as a trivia.

Comment: I'm sure some will be and others won't. I don't know what RPG connection you see in `man` but it's just the obvious three letter abbreviation of _manual_. And ELF stands for "executable and linkable format". In any case, why would these be RPG things and not fantasy things? Yes, *nix folks tend to be geeky, and many are into fantasy and RPGs, so some names are bound to be on purpose but I doubt you'll find any general trend and, if there is one, it is more likely to be a trend of Fantasy tropes than RPG ones.

Comment: Both the examples you vote solidly predate Linux

Comment: Welcome to the flock - but I think your question may have better chances in the Retrocomputing community, as it is more related to historical issues: https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @j4nd3r53n I respectfully disagree, for two reasons: this is a question about UNIX/Linux only, and concerns also commands/tools/standards/names that are currently in use.

Comment: @dr_ Thank you for your respect :-) I still think I am right, though - the OP's question is about how these things came about, not so much about how to use the commands or similar, so I think a community that focuses on the history of things might be better suited. This is not a criticism of the question, which I think displays a good level of curiosity.

Comment: @j4nd3r53n please don't recommend a site unless you are active there and familiar with their scope. Since they consider current software, including older versions of current software, [explicitly off topic](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), I don't know if they would accept this. I don't see you active there, do you _know_ that this would be on topic?

Comment: Questions like https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/4686/where-do-command-line-switches-originate-from suggest maybe yes, though I'm not really competent to answer.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you're (mostly) imagining things.  Sorry.

Some UNIX/Linux names are clearly jokes; for instance, [ORC vs DWARF](https://marc.info/?l=linux-kernel&m=150093945309763). Others, such as ELF and `man`, are almost certainly not.  Such cultural references are often in the nerdy domains of fantasy and sci-fi, but may also be found in mythology (the `hydra` and `medusa` login cracker tools) or history (the "Jack the Ripper" password cracker, or the ROM burner program "Nero" -- [got it?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Fire_of_Rome)).

Besides, this is not confined to the realm of UNIX, or of computers altogether. The [MACHOs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Massive_compact_halo_object) vs [WIMPs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weakly_interacting_massive_particle) theories in astrophysics is a good example.

It's just the human nature of producing jokes.  And people that work in computing and scientific domains tend to be geekier than other people, I think.